# How to skip already created tables while importing mysql dump by command line

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any way to skip already created tables while importing ? I am trying to import 2GB of database using command prompt but the operation is aborted by mistake. Now if i will do the import again it will drop each table and create it again, That will take very long time.

I want to skip those tables from import which is already created or can i start it from where it was aborted ? I am using this command

```
mysql -u root -p my_database_name < db_dump.sql
```

Comment: You should have dumped it with `create table if not exists`..

Comment: Yes i know Matteo but got the dump from other guy and now it is not possible to create the dump again

Answer (score 14):

Run your dump through a filter which replaces each 'CREATE TABLE' with 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS', like in

```
cat db_dump_sql | sed "s/CREATE TABLE /CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /g" | mysql -uroot -p my_database_name
```

Or edit db_dump.sql and search/replace interactively.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Well creating new dump is not possible now.

Answer (score -1):

1. rename table name to new table name
2. add ignore keyword, example (insert ignore into table)